# Bootstrap 3 responsive on container-width not screen-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and am used to working with screen-width, now when it goes below a certain screen-width, the rows become horizontal instead of spread over columns.

However, I want my container to be the screen-width, so if the container-width would be <768px, the lines become horizontal.

I've tried using .container-fluid but it's not working for me. How can I fix this?

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">Test</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really clear. 200px is a fixed width. Bootstrap's grid is fluid, based on percentages. The .container is fixed at different breakpoints, and the children are percentages of that fixed with. .container-fluid is 100% all the time. col-sm breaks at 768px so under that the layout stacks, if you want to have it side by side, use col-xs-6.

Comment: But why the `width:200px`?

Comment: Sounds like you want [Element Queries](http://responsiveimagescg.github.io/eq-usecases/), but that technology doesn't exist yet. Welcome to the Web, where all the good features are missing.

Comment: it indeed sounds like I'm talking about Element Queries. Is it somehow possible to make a div behave like a window/document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your columns to collapse, use col-xs instead of col-sm.

Like this:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:200px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="background:red">Test</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="background:yellow">Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This ain't an answer to the question, This might only solve this specific problem but doesn't provide a generic "relative to container/parent" mechanism.